# rxjs retryWhen not always firing

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an app that uses tokens from Google's javascript authorisation api for authentication. I have a function request that makes all requests for me. When my token expires I want to refresh it in a retryWhen block and then retry the failed call.

```
request<T>(args:{ path: string, params?: any }):Rx.Observable<T> {
    console.log( `make request for: ${args.path}` );

    return this.loadClientDetails()
        .flatMap<T>( clientDetails => {
            console.log( `creating request for: ${args.path}` );
            const request:HttpRequest<T> = gapi.client.request(args);
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise<IHasResult<T>>( <any>request)
                .map( result => { return result.result } );
            }
        )
        .retryWhen( errors => {

            return errors.flatMap( currentError => {

                console.log( `Error status: ${currentError.result.error.code}` );

                if(currentError.result.error.code == 401) {
                    console.log( `not authorized, attempting auth for ${args.path}` );
                    if( !this.refreshToken ) {
                        console.log( `creating refresh token for ${args.path}` );
                        this.refreshToken = this.askForAuthentication( this.clientDetails,this.authorizationScopes, true)
                            .do( _ => {
                                console.log( `refresh token complete ${args.path}` );
                                this.refreshToken = null;
                            } ).shareReplay(1);
                    } else {
                        console.log( `returning existing refresh token for ${args.path}` );
                    }

                    return this.refreshToken;
                }

                return Rx.Observable.throw( currentError );
            } )
            .do(
                _ => {console.log(`flatmap onNext for ${args.path}`)},
                _ => {console.log(`flatmap error for ${args.path}`)},
                () => {console.log(`flatmap complete for ${args.path}`)}
        );
        } )
        .do(
          _ => {console.log(`result returned for path: ${args.path}`)},
          error => { console.log( `error returned for path: ${args.path} Error: ${error}` ) }
        );
}
```

So:

1. loadClientDetails makes sure that the client ID for the app is loaded from a json file
2. We then use flatMap to create an observable that actually loads the data
3. retryWhen decides if the error was due to the permissions expiring (status 401)
4. If it was it creates an observable for requesting new authentication to refresh the token
5. If a refreshToken stream already exists is just returns that and shares the result
6. If the error was not a permission issue it just throws the original error

This all seems to be working but for only one of my 2 calls that are failing. At startup the app loads userInfo and cahnnels:

- https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
- https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels

The logs I get are:

```
make request for: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
googleAuthenticationService.ts:105 creating request for: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
googleAuthenticationService.ts:95 make request for: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:105 creating request for: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:115 Error status: 401
googleAuthenticationService.ts:118 not authorized, attempting auth for https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:120 creating refresh token for https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:166 Asking for authentication: 951450855116-36vi2ec5eo6m2972oke8k4l7tp29irrn.apps.googleusercontent.com
googleAuthenticationService.ts:115 Error status: 401
googleAuthenticationService.ts:118 not authorized, attempting auth for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
googleAuthenticationService.ts:127 returning existing refresh token for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
googleAuthenticationService.ts:171 authorisation granted
googleAuthenticationService.ts:123 refresh token complete https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:136 flatmap onNext for https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:105 creating request for: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
googleAuthenticationService.ts:136 flatmap onNext for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
commentatorController.ts:75 loading all comment threads: 386.773ms
googleAuthenticationService.ts:142 result returned for path: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
headerController.ts:43 User info loaded
```

I can see that the flatmap within the retryWhen fires for both calls as there is a flatMap onNext line for both.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here and why one of the calls never retries?
Thanks